# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't know much about coding or Access at all, except for a a few weeks of using Access during a college course. While messing around with a database, I must have accidentally changed something, which won't allow one of my forms to open. The messages says

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

The only problem is that I have no idea what correct coding  language should look like, so I'm hoping someone can help me find the issue in the following code.

```
SELECT 
FROM [Pant Inventory]
RIGHT JOIN ([Coat Inventory]
RIGHT JOIN Gear
ON ([Coat Inventory].[Issued To] = Gear.[Last Name]) AND ([Coat Inventory].[Number] = Gear.[Alpha Coat Number]))
ON ([Pant Inventory].[Issued To] = Gear.[Last Name]) AND ([Pant Inventory].[Number] = Gear.[Alpha Pant Number]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some fields to return in the SELECT statement. You need to add some of your fields from your table between the SELECT and the FROM statements. I've added the [Issued To] column as an example below:

```
SELECT [Pant Inventory].[Issued To]
FROM       [Pant Inventory]
RIGHT JOIN ([Coat Inventory]
RIGHT JOIN gear
    ON ([Coat Inventory].[Issued To] = gear.[Last Name]) AND ([Coat Inventory].[Number] = gear.[Alpha Coat Number]))
    ON ([Pant Inventory].[Issued To] = gear.[Last Name]) AND ([Pant Inventory].[Number] = gear.[Alpha Pant Number]);
```